# integral over domain $1_{(x+y≥100)}$

Tags: probability, integration, convolution

The problem is:

Compute: $\frac {1}{40^2}\int_{40}^{80}\int_{40}^{80} (100-x)1_{(x+y≥100)}dxdy$

my attempt:

$$=\frac {1}{40^2}\int_{40}^{80}\int_{100-x}^{80} (100-x) dydx = \frac {1}{40^2}\int_{40}^{80}(100-x)(x-20)dx = 36.67$$ But, the solution claims: $$\frac {1}{40^2}\int_{40}^{80}\int_{40}^{80} (100-x)1_{(x+y≥100)}dxdy = 33.33$$

Where am I going wrong? Is there a piece I am cutting off?

If you could also show me all the steps, that'd be great.

Comment: you cut it wrongly. you have included in your integration the triangular region with vertices (80,20), (40,60) and (80,40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help. You should divide it into two parts.

The picture on the left is the desired region. The picture on the right shows the region you are integrating on.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was having a hard time envisioning where I added an extra piece.